# C++ overloading operator< error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

Why am I receiving an error when I do not put `const` in the function `bool operator<(const Node& otherNode) //const`?

```
stl_algo.h:91: error: passing 'const Node' as 'this' argument of 'bool Node::operator<(const Node&)' discards qualifiers
```

Should all the overloaded operators be constant?

```
class Node {
public:
    double coordinate;

    bool operator==(const Node& other) const{
        return coordinate == other.coordinate;
    }

    bool operator<(const Node& other) const{
        return coordinate < other.coordinate;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all operators, but `==` and `<` should definitely be made `const`, yes. They logically don't modify either of the objects being compared.

The error likely comes from calling a non-`const` method from a `const` one, e.g.:

```
bool isSmaller(const Node& other) const
{
   return *this < other;
}
```

In this case, since the method `isSmaller` is `const`, `this` is implicitly a `const` object, therefore `operator <` also has to be `const` in order for the call within that context to be valid.

From the error message, it appears that `Node::operator <` is being called on a `const` object, from a function in `stl_algo.h` - sorting/ordering functions, hashing functions, etc.

Comment: Yes I was having a quiz on programming and then I panic because the compare overloading operator wasn't working, then I just put the const and it worked, but I was in doubt if all operators must be const. Now I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison operators, such as `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==`, `!=` should operate on `const` objects in general, because it makes no sense if any objects being compared can be changed by the comparison. But you could declare the comparisons as non-member functions in order to ensure symmetry between both operands.

```
class Node {
public:
    double coordinate;
};
inline operator<(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs)
{
  return lhs.coordinate < rhs.coordinate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to delete the const modifier of the method? Also, as @LuchianGrigore sugest, you can use the `this` keyword:

```
bool operator< (const Node& other) {
    return this.coordinate < other.coordinate;
}
```

Comment: Yes If I don't put `const` I have the error, whereas if I put it, it works correctly. I just wanted to know if the operators should be all const functions.

Comment: I've never declared a method as const for that. I don't understand why you are getting this error. Take a look at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/